# How to add element to a nested array

Tags: mongodb, f#

When I try to add an item to a list like this:

```ml
open MongoDB.Driver

type SegmentId = string

type SegmentRM =
    { id : SegmentId      
      users: string list }

let addUserToSegment (collection : IMongoCollection<SegmentRM>) (id: SegmentId) (usr: string) =
    let filter = Builders.Filter.Eq((fun x -> x.id), id)
    let update = Builders.Update.Push<string>((fun x -> x.users), usr)
    collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update)
```

I have a compilation error 
`No overloads match for method 'Push'. The available overloads are shown below.`
And also tried with `users: string[]` with the same error.
Anybody knows how to avoid this compilation error?

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to include the list of overloads? That might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you call this [Builders.Update.Push](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Update_1_Push__1.htm) method, you'll have to explicitly cast or convert the list to a sequence,either directly or by calling [Seq.ofList](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L789) which does just that :

```
[<CompiledName("OfList")>]
let ofList (source : 'T list) =
    (source :> seq<'T>)
```

The common and far more readable way is to use `Seq.ofList` so you should use :

```
let update = Builders.Update.Push<string>((fun x -> x.users |> Seq.ofList), usr)
```

**Explanation**

The reason for this is that `Push` expects a function that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Its syntax is :

```
static member Push : 
    memberExpression : Expression<Func<'TDocument, IEnumerable<'TValue>>> * 
    value : 'TValue -> UpdateBuilder<'TDocument>
```

A list [does implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/6819e1c769269edefcea2263c98f993e90b623e2/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3086) :

```
type List<'T> = 
   | ([])  :                  'T list
   | (::)  : Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list -> 'T list
   interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T>
   ...
```

The F# compiler can't implicitly cast to the interface in the question's case though.

A `seq` on the other hand is [a type alias for `IEnumerable<T>`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/6819e1c769269edefcea2263c98f993e90b623e2/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3287) :

```
type seq<'T> = IEnumerable<'T>
```

`Seq.ofList` will cast the `users` list to the `IEnumerable<string>` that `Push` expects

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error says that `string list` is not compatible with `IEnumerable<string>`. However `string seq` is so you should define your type as follows

```
type SegmentRM =
    { id : SegmentId      
      users: string seq }
```

Comment: Lists *do* implement `IEnumerable<T>` and therefore *are* compatible with those interfaces. Using them in this case # requires explicit casting though. There's no reason to change the storage type

Comment: I struggle to find anywhere that F# list module somehow is connected with .NET List<T> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list-module-%5Bfsharp%5D

Comment: It's not. I said it implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which is why `Seq.ofList` works. All it does is upcast to `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: As for the docs, check the [Collections.List<'T> Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list%5b't%5d-union-%5bfsharp%5d), not the List module